# R data.table use if statement in lapply

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, lapply

I would like to convert some columns from numbers to date format; and I'm thinking about using the following code:

```
colList <- c("Date1","Date2")
dataDT[, (colList) := lapply(.SD, function(x){
  if (x == 0) {NA}
  else {as.Date(x, origin = "1900-01-01")}
}), .SDcols = colList]
```

Basically, if the value is 0, then use NA rather than "1900-01-01".
Now the problem is:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x == 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: I would think `ifelse` might be safer. The `if` function is not vectorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "ifelse" instead of "if" in this case:

```
ifelse (x == 0,NA, as.Date(x, origin = "1900-01-01"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `replace`:

```
dataDT[, (colList) := lapply(.SD, 
        function(x) as.Date(replace(x, x==0, NA), origin = "1900-01-01")),
    .SDcols = colList]
```